# Javascript - Div/Image Slide down from the top

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidedown

I've been trying to simply make a picture slide down from the top (outside of the div) to the position it's supposed to be. I've found some other people asking for something similar but so far nothing worked for me. What am I supposed to do to make it work? (Yes I'm just starting with using Javascript)
I'm using JQuery and this is my Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

function slide(){
    $(".head").delay(100).animate({"top":"400px"},500);}
});
```

It's supposed to make the picture in this div move.

```
<div id="content">
    <img src="img/contact_header.png" alt="headerContact" class="head" /><br />
    <p> Text here </p>
</div>
```

The div and the class have the following CSS settings

```
#content {
    width: 800px;
    padding: 0 0 40px 0; 
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-top: 160px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    float: left;
}

.head { top: -200px; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j9rBz/1/

You have to specify `position:relative` to the wrapper div, and `position:absolute` to the image.

Also, keep the image hidden with `display:none` and `opacity:0`. Before animating starts you `show()` the image and then specify `opacity:1` as part of the animation.

Comment: Thanks, this actually works for me. I still have to figure out how to still keep the header div fixed above it (since it's not anymore), but now since it's working I know how to keep going. :) Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things wrong with your code :

1. Your `<img>` doesn't have a closing tag (`/>`).

   `<img src="img/contact_header.png" alt="headerContact" class="head" />`
2. You have declared the `slide()` function, but are not calling it :

   `$(document).ready(function(){`

   ```
   function slide(){
       $(".head").delay(100).animate({
           "top":"400px"
       },500);
   }
   slide(); //<- calling the function
   ```

   `});`
3. Your `<img>` should have `position:absolute;` and its parent i.e. `#content` should have `position:relative;` for the top positioning to work.

Here's a working example : http://jsfiddle.net/bvjdz/3/
(I have increased the delays for animation be visible properly

Answer (score 1):

I've created a fiddle from your code

http://jsfiddle.net/ctrJD/

You need to animate `marginTop`

Answer (score 0):

set `position:relative` on your content div and `position: absolute` on your img. That should get you to a point you can work the rest out to get it how you want, if my assumption of the problem is correct